# Resize an Image's Particular Region

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how to resize a particular region of an image and not the entire thing. For instance, could I specify that I want the left half of an image to have a width of 25% or 250px?

The site I am working on is http://inktank.site90.net
The section that I am trying to work on is the cutout over designer+coder (top of website).

I want the image with the holes to span the width of the browser, but I don't want to distort the part of the image that has holes.

I have tried placing a div to the left and right, that has the correct color, and wrote a script so the divs fill any space that is available. This solution works in theory, but when I tested it in a browser it lagged. The divs to the left and write took too long to resize.

I would greatly appreciate any tips for solving this issue.

Comment: Have you considered using SVGs?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a div around the image area like so (with what ever class you want, i called it white_background:

```
<div class="white_background">
    <div class="center" id="portholes">
    <div class="redband" id="portholes_band"></div>
    <img class="center" id="cutout" src="/css/images/phole_opaque.png" width="960" height="165" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

Then just define that class as:

```
.white_background{
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: change background to what ever color you want

Comment: probably would not work because the holes are transparent so instead of showing the letters it will show white

Comment: Should work if you make the new div before the div that had the actual portholes

Comment: it would not achieve the same effect, when you scroll the page, the holes will show the white background instead of the body pattern

Comment: Why don't you just merge the images into one?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the `phole_opaque.png` wide enough for quite wide screens, and give `#portholes` an extra line of CSS: `{overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: I think that is the best solution for now. Thank you.